# Use GCM on AWS EC2 server

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup the notification system for my mobile App. We have our server hosted on EC2. 
Is there a way to setup and use the GCM services without using the SNS services. Is SNS mandatory to use to send notifications through AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use SNS on AWS - we do it without - the code is too extensive to post here, but take a look at this [example](https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017) which is in PHP

You can use Google AppEngine quite easily (free) full examples/tutorials [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints) and [here](http://smallsoftlab.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/push-notification-services-with-android.html).